# How to fetch string after "=" in a multi line column value using oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column having multi line value and each line is kind of key value pair (separated by = sign and probably ending with new line breaks)

Example value in one cell in the column:

| List of key value pair |
| --- |
| key00=value00 <\n> key01=value01 <\n> key02=value02 |

I am looking for a SQL (Oracle) query to find the specific key (say Key01) and display it in following format

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| Key01 | Value01 |

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID COL
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 key00=value00
           key01=value01
           key02=value02
```

Subquery returns substring that begins with the "key" value (passed as a parameter), while outer query splits that substring into *key* and *value* themselves:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(str, '^\w+') key,
  2         regexp_substr(str, '\w+$') value
  3  from (select regexp_substr(col, '&par_key=\w+') str
  4        from test
  5       );
Enter value for par_key: key01

KEY             VALUE
--------------- ---------------
key01           value01

SQL>
```